# Automatically send an email if a cell is empty in Google Sheets by a certain time

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple tracker running in Google sheets —- information gets imported into the sheet daily from a CSV, the info is used to fill an order, and an order number is filled in to a cell next to that row. However, I’d like to ensure that all orders are being filled by having an email get sent out at the end of the day if a cell does not have an order number.

For example, if a cell in Column B has a value and a cell in Column F does not, send an email notifying that row # has not been filled. I know that MailApp would be the way to go for the email part, but I’m unsure how to handle the if statement portion.

`function EmailReminder () {`

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Order Tracker");`

`var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange('F99').getValue() ;`

`if (valueToCheck == 0) { MailApp-sendEmail ("ceo@google.com”, "Army Exchange Empty Cells", valueToCheck + "is empty.");`
`}`

`}`

This is incomplete and doesn’t take into account both cells or the comparison, but it’s as far as I’ve gotten. I get an error when I try to run even this.

Comment: Take care about the syntax... MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com", "TPS reports", "Where are the TPS reports?"); Example from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
function EmailReminder() {

  const [colB, colF] = [2, 6] // B and F

  let message = ``

  const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                               .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
                               .getDataRange()
                               .getValues()

  values.filter(row => row[colB-1] !== `` && row[colF-1] === ``)
        .forEach(result => {
          const index = values.findIndex(row => String(row) === String(result))
          message += `Row ${index+1} is empty.\n`
        })

  MailApp.sendEmail(`ceo@google.com`, `Army Exchange Empty Cells`, (message.length) ? message : `All orders filled.`)

}
```

**Commented:**

```
function EmailReminder() {

  const [colB, colF] = [2, 6] 

  let message = ``

  const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                               .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
                               .getDataRange()
                               .getValues()
  
  // Filter values to only rows that include a missing F column.
  values.filter(row => row[colB-1] !== `` && row[colF-1] === ``)
        // For each result,
        .forEach(result => {
          // Find the row number...
          const index = values.findIndex(row => String(row) === String(result))
          // and append it to our email body.
          message += `Row ${index+1} is empty.\n`
        })

  // Send the email with a message body containing the list of above orders, or "All orders filled".
  MailApp.sendEmail(`ceo@google.com`, `Army Exchange Empty Cells`, (message.length) ? message : `All orders filled.`)

}
```

Comment: Seems to be getting closer, but the getting the ‘Row $(index+1)’ and so on portion to actually show the row and index as a part of the message isn’t working. When removing the index:row portion from the quotes and appending it to the rest of the message, I get a “Syntax error: missing )”.

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working about the message section?

Comment: As is, it sends an email saying “Row ${index+1}: ${row[colB-1]} is empty”, instead of the actual cell coordinates.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible, did you copy and paste my above code or type it?

Answer (score -1):

Run this function at end of day, or as a time-driven Installable trigger.

There are two parts

- a quick test of the number of records in Column B compared to Column F

  - if the numbers match, then do nothing
- loop through values in Column F

  - if a cell is empty, then add the Row number to an array
  - at the end, "join" the array values
  - send an email with the joined values as the body of the email

---

```
function EmailReminder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  // quick check based on length of arrays
  var colBData = data.map(function(e){return e[1]})
  var colFData = data.map(function(e){return e[5]})
  var colBDataLen = colBData.filter(String).length;
  var colFDataLen = colFData.filter(String).length;
  if (colBDataLen == colFDataLen){
    // no gaps in Column F
    // do nothing
    return
  }

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()

  var tempArray = []

  // loop through Column F
  // if empty, then push Column B value onto array
  for(var i=0;i<lr;i++){
    if(colFData[i] !== ""){
      // ColF is not blank
      // do nothing
      continue
    }
    tempArray.push(["Row#"+(i+1)])
  }
 
  var recipient = "xyz@mail.com"
  var subject = "Here's your missing rows"
  var body = tempArray.join('\n')

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, 
            subject, 
            body);
  }
```

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image]

---

**MESSAGE BODY OUTPUT (per execution log)**

[image]

Comment: It successfully sends an email if both B and F are blank, but not if F is blank and B is not.

Comment: Not according to my testing. It's time for you to supply some test data. Also would you clarify whether there are blanks in Column B. In short, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) AND provide an example of the expected outcome for a successful solution.